# why window.external.menuArguments.setTimeout doesn't work via IE context menu

Tags: internet-explorer, settimeout, setinterval

I'm writing a context menu extension for IE 6/7/8/9. I use window.external.menuArguments as current window object. This works fine for most common apis except setTimeout/setInterval. I tested it in IE 6-9, setTimeout doesn't work at all and setInterval causes memory exhausted in some cases. is there a work-around and am i missing any important tips in MSDN documents?

```
window.external.menuArguments.setTimeout(function() {
    alert("setTimeout OK");
},100);
window.external.menuArguments.setInterval(function() {
    alert("setInterval OK");
},100);
```

The disappointing IE doesn't give me any alerts in above test code.

Comment: What type of extension does your code use? Specifically, does it show a window, or is it the silent type where the window closes immediately? My first guess is that it's destructing and taking down your callbacks with it. If you inject the script into the parent window directly (e.g. createElement with a script tag)) does it work?

Comment: It's a context menu extension for IE. I've figured it out by injecting the script into the parent window directly via createElement with a script tag. window.external.menuArguments might have many limitations to dynamically alter current window object and document object. Events set by window.external.menuArguments will not be fired, including setTimeout/setInterval, and other DOM events, like window.external.menuArguments.document.body.attachEvent

Answer (score 0):

The environment that Microsoft provides for you via externals is an interesting beast.  You actually have two windows, the first window which contains the `external` variable and the target browser window you just right-clicked into is provided via the `external.menuArguments` variable.  For conversation's sake we'll call them the parent and child window, though it is not the same relationship as a `window.open()` call.

So in this situation you have two setInterval/setTimeout functions to choose from:

```
window.external.menuArguments.setTimeout(function first() { console.log('child'); }, 1);

window.setTimeout(function second() { external.menuArguments.console.log('parent'); }, 1);
```

But neither of these functions will execute as you would expect, though for different reasons.

The first one will execute setTimeout, but it will pass in a function reference that your child window cannot execute because the function itself is defined in the parent window.  So external.menuArguments has no way to call `first`.

The second one will execute setTimeout, and the parent `window` will have a reference to `second` so it could call the method on the next event loop.  But the externals feature to IE doesn't pump all messages from the message loop before exiting.  So your method will be queued, but the code will quit after the first message loop.

You can prevent the parent window from exiting immediately by opening a new window via `window.open('about:blank');` which will keep window running until the popup process is fully loaded.  On my laptop this gives me about 600 milliseconds of interval time to work with.

I'm currently trying to devise a hack to keep the process running while not dead-locking the message loop like what occurs with a for/while loop.  My guess is something in the AJAX/FSO ActiveXObject realm will do, but I haven't found a solution yet.  My situation requires the parent window process to execute forever, so I'll post back if I find a workaround.

Funny enough, just putting an `alert()` call after the setTimeout will run the setTimeout callback when the interval is less than 10 milliseconds for me, so just showing an alert takes a couple milliseconds before releasing the parent window process.

The other pain is that for legacy purposes the JS engine is version 7 or 8, so no JSON object in the parent instance, which means object serialization and deserialization will have different prototype chains between the two instances if you use external.menuArguments.JSON object instead.  And no  Object.keys() or any other modern addition to the language.

Documentation as a whole for this realm is really, really sparse, so it's typically a trial and error experiment for anything useful.

Comment: Turns out using an HTA for the long-running parent process solved all of my problems.  Not only does the privileged cross-domain access become permanent for both iframes and popup windows, but it also uses the latest jvm/ie control.  I'm still using an enternal menuArguments script but it serializes json to the file system where the hta checks for new files to be processed.